# How to convert from Platform::String^ to Platform::Guid^

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

It is super easy to go from `Platform::Guid^` to `Platform::String^` with the `ToString()` method. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh755797.aspx) for more details.

But how do we convert from `Platform::String^` to `Platform::Guid^`?

---

Edit:

Both `CLSIDFromString` and `IIDFromString` will do. Please refer to the accepted answer as an example. Also please `#include <wrl\wrappers\corewrappers.h>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call in the help from the [IIDFromString() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Sample code:

```
Platform::String^ example("{6DDAD7B6-F8C5-42D9-B4EB-59FE94A4EA5F}");
GUID rawguid;
HRESULT hr = IIDFromString(example->Data(), &rawguid);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    Platform::Guid guid(rawguid);
    // etc..
}
```